# Adding a gallery to lightbox1

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm trying to add an image gallery function to the original lightbox -- http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/. I'm utilizing it in an addon to ContentFlow, and  want the user to be able to navigate the previous and next pictures after they choose an image.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First off you need a backend either you upload your image with ftp to a folder or you can create a plugin or a widget with your favourite cms. Then for the grid you can use the Jquery plugin masonry. In fact it's sort the image like a treemap but it's perfect for any horizontal grid, too.  Above the grid you can add the Jquery Anything Slider to navigate through each category. When you click on a grid thumbnail it can open a lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful or not but I wrote a skin for the image gallery software [Jalbum](http://www.jalbum.net)
 that integrates a number of Lightboxes (not the original Lightbox though) with ContentFlow.
Here is the [Link](http://jalbum.net/en/skins/skin/LightBoxes/)